# Python Generator Expression for Accumulating Dictionary Values

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

A generator expression is throwing off a large number of tuple pairs eg. in list form:

```
pairs = [(3, 47), (6, 47), (9, 47), (6, 27), (11, 27), (23, 27), (41, 27), (4, 67), (9, 67), (11, 67), (33, 67)]
```

For each pair in pairs, with key = pair[0] and value = pair[1], I want to feed this stream of pairs into a dictionary to cumulatively add the values for the respective keys. The obvious solution is:

```
dict_k_v = {}
for pair in pairs:
    try:
        dict_k_v[pair[0]] += pair[1]
    except:
        dict_k_v[pair[0]] = pair[1]

>>> dict_k_v
{33: 67, 3: 47, 4: 67, 6: 74, 9: 114, 11: 94, 41: 27, 23: 27}
```

However, could this be achieved with a generator expression or some similar construct that doesn't use a for-loop?

EDIT

To clarify, the generator expression is throwing off a large number of tuple pairs:

(3, 47), (6, 47), (9, 47), (6, 27), (11, 27), (23, 27), (41, 27), (4, 67), (9, 67), (11, 67), (33, 67) ...

and I want to accumulate each key-value pair into a dictionary (see Paul McGuire's answer) as each pair is being generated.  The pairs = list[] statement was unnecessary and sorry about that.  For each pair (x,y), x is an integer and y can be an integer or decimal/float.

My generator expression is of the form:

```
((x,y) for y in something() for x in somethingelse())
```

and want to accumulate each (x,y) pair into a defaultdict.  Hth.

Comment: What is this aversion to for-loops lately?  A for-loop wrapped around an accumulation into a defaultdict is the cleanest solution.

Comment: I just had a long discussion about all the options for pushing into a dict and it turns out that the most efficient way to code this is with if key in dict: / else: (not that you wanted to use a for loop :-)

Comment: @PaulMcGuire The prime aversion to for-loops is the likely performance hit when data sets are very large and/or the operation is being performed continuosly.  One option is Cython but I like to see if there is a Python solution that uses built-in functions.

Comment: @pietdelport In his response, Paul McGuire explicitly adds to the question what I had assumed obvious (oops!) ie. "... accept each key-value pair sent to it, and accumulate them all into a defaultdict passed into it".  I've added this to the original question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For discussion, here is a simple generator function to give us some data:

```
from random import randint
def generator1():
    for i in range(10000):
        yield (randint(1,10), randint(1,100))
```

And here is the basic solution that uses a Python for-loop to consume the generator and tally up counts for each key-value pair

```
from collections import defaultdict

tally = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in generator1():
    tally[k] += v

for k in sorted(tally):
    print k, tally[k]
```

Will print something like:

```
1 49030
2 51963
3 51396
4 49292
5 51908
6 49481
7 49645
8 49149
9 48523
10 50722
```

But we can create a coroutine that will accept each key-value pair sent to it, and accumulate them all into a defaultdict passed into it:

```
# define coroutine to update defaultdict for every
# key,value pair sent to it
def tallyAccumulator(t):
    try:
        while True:
            k,v = (yield)
            t[k] += v
    except GeneratorExit:
        pass
```

We'll initialize the coroutine with a tally defaultdict, and get it ready to accept values by sending a None value to it:

```
# init coroutine
tally = defaultdict(int)
c = tallyAccumulator(tally)
c.send(None)
```

We could use a for loop or a list comprehension to send all of the generator values to the coroutine:

```
for val in generator1():
    c.send(val)
```

or

```
[c.send(val) for val in generator1()]
```

But instead, we'll use a zero-sized deque to process all the generator expression's values without creating an unnecessary temporary list of None's:

```
# create generator expression consumer
from collections import deque
do_all = deque(maxlen=0).extend

# loop thru generator at C speed, instead of Python for-loop speed
do_all(c.send(val) for val in generator1())
```

Now we look at the values again:

```
for k in sorted(tally):
    print k, tally[k]
```

And we get another list similar to the first one:

```
1 52236
2 49139
3 51848
4 51194
5 51275
6 50012
7 51875
8 46013
9 50955
10 52192
```

Read more about coroutines at David Beazley's page: http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/

Comment: This answer is well-written, but poorly motivated: using coroutine-style generators doesn't add any value to the solution over using a plain generator consumer.

Comment: @PietDelport - well thanks at least for not downvoting me. I agree that this is extreme overkill for this particular problem, but it seemed like a nice exercise for showing a coroutine demonstration.

Comment: Got my generator to work with: do_all(c.send((x,y)) for y in something() for x in somethingelse()) with the defaultdict tally containing the accumulated values for the respective keys.

Comment: Your nested loop will return all pairs of x and y values. If that is really what you want, you can rewrite as `for x,y in itertools.product(something(), somethingelse())`  If you just want to pair up the values returned by the two functions, use zip instead of product. Note also that somethingelse() gets called y times - not sure if product is smart enough to avoid this or not.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Thanks, Paul.  Have enough to get going with.  Co-incidently, was looking at Beazley's co-routines work just recently and now have a perfect example.  Will perform timings between Ignacio's and your solution later.

Comment: This is a very nice writeup about coroutines, a concept which I have so far procrastinated to look at, unfortunately. However, from your description I take it that this generator/consumer approach should also have a performance advantage in addition to the conceptional advantage. I [can't reproduce this](http://ideone.com/UQHbi), though, neither in Python 2.7.2 nor in 3.2.2. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: It may be that the real advantages to coroutines arise when the work to be done involves i/o to databases or remote systems, and the coroutines themselves can be managed within a dispatching framework, much like Twisted does with managing Deferreds. This permits a single thread of execution to overlap computing with i/o waiting on multiple tasks concurrently, simulating threads. For something so deterministic and synchronous as this example, coroutines may be just an academic exercise.

Comment: (continued) If you added a random sleep to the coroutine, and broke up the work across several coroutines, routing to each in turn, maybe then you would see some benefit, and some potential for scaleability.

Answer (score 6):

You can use tuple destructuring and a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to shorten that loop a lot:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in pairs: d[k] += v
```

This still uses a for-loop, but you don't have to handle the case where a key hasn't been seen before. I think this is probably the best solution, both readability-wise and performance-wise.

#### Proof of concept using `groupby`

That said, you *could* do it using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), but it's a bit of a hack:

```py
import itertools
dict((k, sum(v for k,v in group)) for k, group 
     in itertools.groupby(sorted(pairs), lambda (k,v): k))
```

Also, this should actually be less performant than the first approach, because an in-memory list of all the pairs needs to be created for the sorting.

Comment: Given that the OP states that they are working with "a generator expression" and a "large number" of pairs, I would side with the defaultdict solution over any of the sort+groupby solutions, as the for loop cleanly processes the stream of pairs, summarizing the total into the entries of the defaultdict, and no intermediate in-memory list of the values needs to be created (as is done internally by sorted).

Comment: @Paul: That's exactly my opinion, but looking back at that answer, it's not absolutely obvious that I consider the solution with a `for`-loop as much better.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> dict((x[0], sum(y[1] for y in x[1])) for x in itertools.groupby(sorted(pairs, key=operator.itemgetter(0)), key=operator.itemgetter(0)))
{33: 67, 3: 47, 4: 67, 6: 74, 9: 114, 11: 94, 41: 27, 23: 27}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `sorted` be comparing lexicographically by default?

Comment: @Niklas: Sure. But I don't care about the second element so I leave it alone so that it doesn't get in `sorted`'s way.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Your solution is short and sweet, performant and fits in with the rest of my code.  Because I asked for a dictionary solution that accumulates the pairs as they are generated, it wouldn't be fair to accept your solution.  Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Haskell has a very nice generic helper for this: `Data.Map`'s [`fromListWith`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map.html#v%3afromListWith).

`fromListWith` is similar to Python's `dict` constructors, but it also accepts an additional *combining function* to combine repeated keys's values. Translating it to Python:

```
def dict_fromitems(items, combine):
    d = dict()
    for (k, v) in items:
        if k in d:
            d[k] = combine(d[k], v)
        else:
            d[k] = v
    return d
```

Using this helper, it's easy to express a multitude of combinations:

```
>>> import operator
>>> dict_fromitems(pairs, combine=operator.add)
{33: 67, 3: 47, 4: 67, 6: 74, 9: 114, 11: 94, 41: 27, 23: 27}

>>> dict_fromitems(pairs, combine=min)
{33: 67, 3: 47, 4: 67, 6: 27, 9: 47, 11: 27, 41: 27, 23: 27}

>>> dict_fromitems(pairs, combine=max)
{33: 67, 3: 47, 4: 67, 6: 47, 9: 67, 11: 67, 41: 27, 23: 27}

>>> dict_fromitems(((k, [v]) for (k, v) in pairs), combine=operator.add)
{33: [67], 3: [47], 4: [67], 6: [47, 27], 9: [47, 67], 11: [27, 67], 41: [27], 2
3: [27]}
```

Note that unlike the solutions using `defaultdict(int)`, this approach is not limited to numeric values, as demonstrated by the list example above. (In general, any monoid is a useful possibility: sets with union/intersection, booleans with and/or, strings with concatenation, and so on.)

**Addendum**:

As other comments pointed out, there's nothing wrong with using a loop for this: it's the appropriate low-level solution. However, it's always good if you can wrap the low-level code in a reusable, higher-level abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this without using *some* form of loop. And using a `for` loop really is the most sensible thing, because you are modifying something in the body of the loop (and not, for example, creating a new iterable or list.) You can, however, simplify the code by using a `collections.defaultdict`, like so:

```
import collections
dict_k_v = collections.defaultdict(int)
for k, v in pairs:
    dict_k_v[k] += v
```

Comment: You can do this with recursion which isn't a looping structure, but I suppose may be "some" form of looping.  That isn't to say you should solve this particular problem with recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a recursive call, however Python is not optimized for tail recursion so you will pay a speed penalty and have the potential for a "recursion to deep" exception.

```
import operator as o
def dict_sum(pairs, totals={}):
  k, v = pairs.pop()
  o.setitem(sum, k, totals.get(k, 0) + v)
  if not pairs:
    return totals
  else:
    return dict_sum(pairs, totals)
```

I would implement it in a for loop:

```
import operator as o
totals={}
for k, v in pairs:
   o.setitem(totals, k, totals.get(k, 0) + v)
```

Answer (score 0):

why wouldn't you want to use a for loop?

```
pairs = [(3, 47), (6, 47), (9, 47), (6, 27), (11, 27), (23, 27), (41, 27), (4, 67), (9, 67), (11, 67), (33, 67)]
result={}
def add(pair):
    k,v=pair
    result[k]=result.get(k,0)+v
map(add,pairs)
print result
```

Answer (score -2):

Something like:

```
dict_k_v = dict(pairs)
```

Comment: This wouldn't do the right thing for repeated keys. (Please, don't delete the answer or we'll just get more people suggesting it.)